# Arrow Function Syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is a follow up to this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file-in-the-browser](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

This provided solution code works, but I need to output the result to an Element instead of the Console.

```
<input type="file" onchange="this.files[0].text().then(t => console.log(t))">
```

I've tried replacing `t => console.log(t)` with `document.getElementById("output").innerText = t` but that results in a Syntax Error.

What is the simplest and shortest way to implement this? Thank you.

I don't really understand arrow functions, but I looked into them and tried a variety of combinations that might work. I assume this has something to do with their syntax.

Comment: Here, the use of the arrow function `t => console.log(t)` is more or less the same thing as 1) defining a function: `function myFunction(t) { console.log(t); }`, and then 2) passing this function as the`then` callback: `this.files[0].text().then(myFunction)` .

Comment: Are you setting `onchange="this.files[0].text().then(t => { document.getElementById('output').innerText = t })"` ? The nested-double-quotes won't have been helping, try single quotes.

Comment: Thanks @motto, this was the issue. Both the missing brackets, which I did not understand, and the nested-double-quotes, which I just didn't think about, for lack of experience.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily a arrow function question. There's a lot going on in that little onchange handler.

```
<input type="file" onchange="this.files[0].text().then(t => document.getElementById('output').innerText = t)">
```

`this` is the file input

`.files[0]` returns the first file selected

`.text()` returns a promise that resolves when the text is read from the file

`.then(` waits for the promise to finish and then calls the arrow function that follows

`t=> document.getElementById('output').innerText = t` is the arrow function. The first paramater `t` will have the text value, so we use that to assign the innerText of your destination element.

Finally, note that I surrounded the id `output` in single quotes, so the HTML parser doesn't think it's the matching close quote `"` for the `onchange` attribute.